# How to get value from WYSIWYG with Javascript or using the help of JQuery maybe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

I want to ask. I wanted to create a blog, but used a Microsoft word-style text editor. If suppose using vanilla javascript or pure javascript or using the help of JQuery?

MY code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- CDN WYSIWYG (TINYMICE) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/fjxlmvgx0f36t65lwkpdwdyrxxahi85ni9wp3e2xp17gjitr/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Text-Area -->
    <textarea id="my_text"></textarea>
    <!-- Button Get Value -->
    <button id="value_button">Get Value</button>

    <script>
        // Install WYSIWYS (TINYMICE)
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: 'a11ychecker advcode casechange export formatpainter image editimage linkchecker autolink lists checklist media mediaembed pageembed permanentpen powerpaste table advtable tableofcontents tinycomments tinymcespellchecker',
            toolbar: 'a11ycheck addcomment showcomments casechange checklist code export formatpainter image editimage pageembed permanentpen table tableofcontents',
            toolbar_mode: 'floating',
            tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
            tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
          });

        // Dom (get id:my_text & value_button)
        let my_text = document.getElementById("my_text");
        let value_button = document.getElementById("value_button");

        // get value in console
        value_button.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            console.log(my_text.value)
        })
      </script>
```

I want to get the value first. Like wanting to write "Thursday"

Perhaps, what appears is
"`<p>Thursday</p>`"

My obstacle, I typed whatever the value is ""(empty)

**Note: My WYSIWYG is TinyMice**

**However, if you have another type of WYSIWYG, I will try it**
Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE has an API to get its current content:

`getContent()` - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent

For some background, when you load TinyMCE it overlays your `textarea` with an `iframe` so when you are typing into TinyMCE you are not updating the `textarea`.

That being said, there is an API call to make TinyMCE push its current content back into the `textarea`:

`triggerSave()` - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#triggersave

...so if you need to do something specifically with the `textarea` you can call `triggerSave()` first.